# How to write equivalent MySQL query in Sequelize.js?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have following three tables `Type`, `Master` and `Config` where `Type` and `Master` is related to each other using `Type_ID` column.

In the third table `Config`, a single record can refer to more than 1 `Master` records hence the `Master` table IDs are placed in comma separated form under column `Master_IDS`.

```
Type
---------------
ID    Type_Name

1     Flat

2     Round

3     Solid


Master
------------------------
ID  Type_ID  Master_Name

1   1        Affix

2   1        Super

3   3        Maven

4   2        Baleno


Config
-----------------------------
ID   Config_Name   Master_IDS

1    Raven         1,3

2    Surplus       3,2
```

I have written a MySQL query which is working fine and giving desired results.

```
SELECT c.Config_Name, t.Type_Name, m.Master_Name 
FROM
Type t inner join Master m on t.ID = m.Type_ID
inner join Config c ON FIND_IN_SET(m.ID, c.Master_IDS) > 0;


---------------------------------------------
ID     Config_Name   Type_Name    Master_Name

1      Raven         Flat         Affix

2      Raven         Solid        Maven

3      Surplus       Solid        Maven

4      Surplus       Round        Super
```

I tried something like

```
mydb.Type.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: mydb.Master,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: mydb.Config,
                        where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('FIND_IN_SET', mydb.Master.ID, Sequelize.col('MasterIds')), '>', 0)
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    })
```

It's not working and throwing error SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Config is not associated to Master

I am new to Sequelize so not able to find more solutions using Sequelize.js syntax for the above select query.

Comment: You are missing relations in the model's files therefore following error - Config is not associated to Master

Comment: Eg - Currencies can have many currency details - 
Currency JSON - https://pastebin.com/LzEJPXWJ        Detail JSON - https://pastebin.com/mg10wEF4

Comment: Hi @RohitDalal, thanks for your comment. I tried to establish relation between them but no luck as the foreign key in Config table is comma separated value (Master table IDs) instead of a single value representing ID from Master table.

Comment: Please see the following code for gettings results from mysql, Separately and linking them with their respective models - https://pastebin.com/W74F8Wq4 and the inner function code link - https://pastebin.com/XHz2AVqu